# How to run Cucumber scenario as a step?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I have one scenario that has many steps, and its whole purpose is data generation, for example:

```
Scenario: Data generation
Given dataGen statement 1
And dataGen statement 2

...
And dataGen statement 100
```

I want to use this entire scenario (i.e. all 100 statements) as a single step in another scenario.  I want to do something like:

```
scenario: Data generation and then assert
(everything in previous scenario)
Then I assert my assertion
```

But it would be silly to copy and paste everything.

Is there a way in Cucumber to make a call to a scenario as a single step?
or to group the 100 statement into some structure as a whole and call it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a way to call a scenario step from another in cucumber-jvm. Some kind of nesting steps is allowed in ruby implementation. You can try the belowin java.

Convert your scenario into scenario outline with two tables with their own tags. When you want to only generate data pass `@Data` tag to `cucumberoptions`of your runner class. And `@DataAndAssert` when both operations are required. Base the logic in the assertion step with the value of the boolean flag.

```
    Scenario Outline: Data generation and then assert
    Given dataGen statement 1
    And dataGen statement 2

    ...
    And dataGen statement 100
    Then I assert my assertion <flag>

    @Data
    Examples: Data Generation Only
    | flag |
    | false |

    @DataAndAssert
    Examples: Data Generation And Assertion
    | flag |
    | true |
```

Comment: it's a workaround. But it's not so convenient if the dataGen is used by a lot of test cases. I am look for something that at least can run a feature in @Before.

Comment: In the @Before hook cucumber will not call features and step definition. If you wanna go that way you will need to call it urself by using a wrapper method which call yout step definition code.

Comment: the thing is '@before' hook will only call java code, i do not want to copy the hundred lines of repetitive java code converted from cucumber step to the @before hook. it defeat the purpose of why i write those dataGen in cucumber in the first place.